# Recommended folder to save on demand images for an IOS and Mac App?

Tags: ios, macos

My app uses custom skins (themes) but I don't want to package them all with the app due to the increasing size. 
When the user selects the skin, it will download image resources from my server.

The question is, where would be the recommended directory to save the files ? To the document directory ? I'm guessing I will not get the benefits of the UIImage(named:) cache system, nor the automatic scale selection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page in the docs should give you a variety of options:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

One major choice to make here is whether you want the contents backed up via iTunes or not.

Also, as you can see on the [UIImage API reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage), you have various initializer options to work with, not only `UIImage(named:)`.

There too you have several considerations to make, such as whether you want images cached or not, as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init):

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.